# Importing columns from a CSV file doesn't work when there's a space in the column header

Tags: python

I want to import a file using Python to do some quality checks (check for dupes etc). It works fine if columns don't have spaces, but for any columns that have spaces I can't get them to work properly.

As soon as I get rid of the space, it works fine.

```
with open(filename) as f:
  reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter = ",")
  for row in reader: 
    for (k,v) in row.items(): 
      columns[k].append(v) 

uniqueid = columns['Unique Identifier']
firstname = columns['FirstName']
lastname = columns['LastName']
email = columns['Email']

print(uniqueid)
```

Comment: I don't think the problem has anything to do having spaces in the csv files header — it's got something to do with `columns`. However your question isn't a [mcve], so it's impossible to tell for sure.

Comment: indeed - you need to include what doesn't work properly and what you want it to do

Answer (score 0):

#Strip white space see what happens

```
 for row in reader: 
    for (k,v) in row.items(): 
      columns[k].append(v)
      columns[k]=columns[k].strip()  #Strip white space
```